# With the new App Transport Security policy, how come older apps still work?

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

As of iOS 9, all connections must be secure and follow a certain criteria. However, older apps that use http connections continue to work without an update. Why is this?

Comment: ATS is only active for apps that link against iOS 9 or later.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Can you post as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW14) ATS is only enabled when you link against iOS 9.0 / macOS 10.11 or later. If you link against an older SDK version your app just continues to work without the ATS requirements.

> If you link your app against an SDK for an operating system older than iOS 9.0 or OS X v10.11, your Internet connections continue to work but ATS is disabled, no matter which version of the operating system your app is running on. ATS is not available on operating systems older than iOS 9.0 or OS X v10.11; those older operating systems ignore the NSAppTransportSecurity key.